# Select/mark specific word in SWT Textfield

Tags: java, text, widget, swt

I've got an SWT Textfield with some text which is added automatically. Now I want to select a specific phrase in the text automatically, so that the user could replace this without the manual selection. But all I've found in the api is the `selectAll()` method, which works but selects ALL the text, not a specific part.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Text#setSelection(int start, int end)`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Text.html#setSelection(int,%20int)) will do what you need.

Example:

```
Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
text.setText("This is some random text");
text.setSelection(5, 7);
```

Looks like this:

[image]